# Changing read only input field text according to radio button selection

Tags: javascript, html, css

the scenario is that i want to set the total price based on user choice of radio buttons, when user chooses one of the radio buttons the price changes accordingly.

here is the the HTML:

```
        <div class="input_box">
            <h4 style="text-align: center;">إختر الباقة</h4>
            <input type="radio" name="package" class="radio" id="pk1" value="70">
            <label for="pk1">بالساعة</label>
            <input type="radio" name="package" class="radio" id="pk2" value="200">
            <label for="pk2">يوم</label>
            <input type="radio" name="package" class="radio" id="pk3" value="2500">
            <label for="pk3">شهر</label>
        </div>
        <div class="input_box">
            <input type="number" placeholder="Total Value" name="price" class="name" id="output">
            <i class="fa fa-money icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
```

i tried to use javaScript solution such as:

```
        <script>
            document.getElementsByName("package").addEventListener("change", function(){
                document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = this.value;// Show the value in output element

        });
        </script>
```

but it seems nothing works for me, i appreciate any help, Thank you :)

Comment: Wouldn't you have to loop through the elements in your nodelist to addEventListener on each individual one of them?

Comment: @seb Exactly, the answer down there have worked for me thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of issues with your code to start with. If you check in the browser console you will see errors and specific line numbers where they occurred - that's always a good place to start.

First, `getElementsByName` returns a collection of elements, so you need to loop over it and attach event listeners one by one. You can't just call `addEventListener` to apply them all at once like you do with jquery, for example. Take a look at the documentation for that function here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName

Second, you're trying to update the `output` element by setting its `innerHTML`, but that element is a number input. You need to update its `value` property instead.

Here's a snippet bringing all that together.

```js
const radios = document.getElementsByName('package')

radios.forEach(function(radio) {
  radio.addEventListener('change', function() {
    document.getElementById("output").value = this.value;
  })
})
```

```html
<div class="input_box">
  <h4 style="text-align: center;">إختر الباقة</h4>
  <input type="radio" name="package" class="radio" id="pk1" value="70">
  <label for="pk1">بالساعة</label>
  <input type="radio" name="package" class="radio" id="pk2" value="200">
  <label for="pk2">يوم</label>
  <input type="radio" name="package" class="radio" id="pk3" value="2500">
  <label for="pk3">شهر</label>
</div>
<div class="input_box">
  <input type="number" placeholder="Total Value" name="price" class="name" id="output">
  <i class="fa fa-money icon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable information i appreciate your help, truly it worked for me and now i do have new knowledge from your answer. Regards